# Characterisation, characterization or charactarisation?

Tags: orthography

Basically, I would like to know which of the above is correct, and in what type of context.

From what I understand, the difference between *characterisation* and *characterization* might be that one of them is used in American English and the other in British English, but what about ***charactarisation***? Is that written incorrectly?

I just found *charactarisation* in the title of a thesis, and I find it difficult to believe that they may have made a mistake in such an obvious place as the title. Maybe it has a different meaning? The title was this:

> Charactarisation of submillimeter galaxies in the field of a protocluster around the high-redshift radio galaxy MRC1138-262

Is that correct, and if so, does it mean something specific?

Comment: No, it's just a spelling error.

Comment: Okay, thank you. And what about *characterisation* and characterization*? Which one is American english and which one is British?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with [most words ending in -isation or -ization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29), *characterisation* is the British English form and *characterization* is the American English form.

*Charactarisation* is just a spelling error; things like that happen even in theses.

Comment: This must have been covered many times but the -ise ending is not the traditional British English ending (i.e. was not used in the early post-war period in Britain, although does occur earlier). It has spread through the newspapers and the dictionary of lowest authority — MS Word.

Comment: There's probably another question on that topic. I'm a continental European and prefer 'British' spelling for everything but the -ise/-ize words.

Comment: — Germanic I assume, but if you were French you would probably prefer the -ise. Although it's completely off-topic, I find it bizarre that the -ize of my youth has been rejected by newspapers such as The Financial Times that are aggressively courting the US market.

Comment: Yes, Dutch (see my profile). Which is quite strange, because our version of the word is *karakteri**s**ering*. Well, that's the literal translation; we'd probably use *kenmerken* in this case.